# Slash ("/") added to my return URL

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I'm creating a Payment for the REST API through the PayPal SDK. Everything seems to work fine, the redirect to paypal, the payment itself. But when I return to my shop from paypal, the returnUrl has a "/" added to its end.

Instead of

```
http://192.168.41.174/confirm
```

I'm being redirected to

```
http://192.168.41.174/confirm/
```

The payload of the payment creation request is:

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {   
    "currency": "EUR",
    "total": "21.27",
    "details": {
      "shipping": "4.99",
      "subtotal": "16.28"
    }
      },
      "description": "Thank you for your purchase!"
    }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://192.168.41.174/confirm",
    "cancel_url": "http://192.168.41.174/checkout"
  }
}
```

So I can pretty much exclude an error on my side. Except if there is another configuration for return URLs that I don't know of?
If I manually remove the added slash, but keep the parameters, the payment can be processed and even captured. It's only the added slash out of nowhere that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal is fixing this issue soon. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/146

For the time being you can add a ? to the end of your urls.

```
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "...confirm?",
    "cancel_url": "...checkout?"
}
```

Comment: This changes my return URL to:

    http://192.168.41.174/confirm?&paymentId=

which is fine for now. Thank you very much!